# git: Copy a version for playing around

Tags: git, production-environment, git-clone

While developing an application, I would like to have at one point a separate copy of my work for experimenting with several changes. Theses changes are not meant to be committed! It's just playing around, to try out various possibilities.

What is the "*best*" way to do this? I found the following possibilities, but would like to get the advice of people who have more experience with git than I do:

1. I could use `git clone` to get a copy of the repository into a different directory, and use it to play around.
2. I could just `cp -r` my current git working directory to the new one.

In case (1), git is aware about the clone, and I could later `rebase` if I really would want to, but it is unlikely that I will ever do this.

In this case, is there something I should be aware of, which makes either solution (1) or (2) preferable? Or is there an even better way to do it?

Comment: What if your playing around actually pays off and you end up producing something of value? Wouldn't you want to be able to merge it into your more stable work? If the answer is yes, you should probably just create a new branch in your repository and "play around" on that branch. You can always discard it if it doesn't pan out so well.

Comment: It needs to be in a separate directory, otherwise I can't work in parallel with the main branch. Following your advice, it would mean that I first use git clone (to get a new project directory for my experiments), and then, within it, created a new branch (which I likely, but not necessarily, will discard in the end). Right?

Comment: *It needs to be in a separate directory, otherwise I can't work in parallel with the main branch.* Not true; you can work in parallel with the main branch. Assuming your working tree is clean (you don't have any uncommitted changes), all you have to do is switch to whichever branch you want to work on is to issue a `git checkout <desired_branch>` command. Besides, no need to clone your original repo. If I were you, I would create a new branch *directly* inside the latter.

Comment: That's the point: The working tree is NOT clean in general. I commit maybe once or twice a day, but I might switch between the playing branch and the working branch anytime back and force. I would consider it inconvenient to always commit the current state. For example, I would hate it to commit a state where my code has syntax errors, but I might want to play around on the other branch before fixing them.

Comment: If you're not ready to commit, you can [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) your changes instead, before switching branches; that's literally *one* command. My point is that there is little incentive for using two separate repositories here, where a couple of branches would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Using a clone/copy

- pros: main repo and its clone/copy are complete silos
- cons: space inefficiency

Using a branch

- pros: space efficiency (Git branches are cheap)
- cons: relatively unwieldy workflow if a lot of stashing is required

---

### Details

You write

> I would like to have at one point a separate copy of my work for experimenting with several changes. [...] What is the "best" way to do this?

You also write in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582423/git-copy-a-version-for-playing-around#comment40025622_25582423) that you're likely to switch back and forth between the original work and its "copy", without committing any changes carried out in the latter.

You have different possible approaches, here; let's review your two suggestions first, and then explore a third possibility. To fix ideas, I'll assume your repository lives in a directory called `main`.

#### 1 - Use `git clone` to get a copy of the repository into a different directory, and use it to play around.

As you suggest, you could produce a clone of `main`, say, into a directory called `exp`,

```
git clone <path-to-main> <path-to-exp>
```

and conduct your crazy experiment in `exp`. The `main` repo would be `exp`'s "upstream", i.e. `exp` would list `main` as one of its remotes under the name `origin`. Therefore, if you made more commits in `main` and wanted to keep `exp` up to date with what's going on in `main`, you could fetch from `main` to `exp` and then merge or rebase in the latter.

The main problem with this approach is **space inefficiency**: because a clone carries the entire history of the original repo with it, you will get a lot of duplicate files on your disk. That may or may not be a problem, depending on the size of your original repo, but it's something to consider.

#### 2 - Just `cp -r` my current git working directory to the new one

That's essentially like cloning `main` but, unless you manually add `main` as a remote of `exp`, you won't be able to fetch from `main` to `exp`. I don't see any advantage in this approach compared to the first one (except, perhaps, that it doesn't involve the risk of accidentally pushing stuff from `exp` to `main`).

#### 3 - Create a new branch directly within your original repo and conduct experiments in it

A third approach is to create a new branch (let's call it `exp`) directly *within* your `main` repo,

```
git branch exp
```

check it out,

```
git checkout exp
```

and conduct your experiment in there. The main advantage of this approach over the other two is space efficiency: Git branches are cheap, in that creating a new one doesn't involve any copying of files.

However, if you make changes while `exp` is checked out but do not commit them, Git will deem your working directory "not clean", and won't allow you to switch back to your `master` branch until you remedy the situation. One possibility for cleaning your repository is to *stash* your uncommitted changes, by running

```
# while on exp, if there are uncommitted changes
git stash save
```

You could then switch back to `master`, do some changes, commit them, switch back to `exp`, and retrieve your stashed changes by running

```
git stash pop
```

If a lot of stashing (`save` and `pop`) is involved, though, you may find this workflow too tedious and unwieldy...

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. The point is not so much in creating / discarding a branch, but that I want to do these experiments in a separate directory, in parallel to developing my "main work" (which I always do in a development branch, btw, and never directly on master). Hence I need two separate directories for working.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to create your own branch from the current state, do your work on this branch (with commiting if you want). At the end, if you want to have your work with the main branch, you could run a `git merge`.

To create a branch from the current state, just run `git checkout -b my_branch`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to create a branch `git checkout -b your-branch-name` and then delete your branch with `git branch -d your-branch-name` when you are done or commit and merge into the original

You may also stay in the same project, do your experiments and then use `git stash` to clean all your work but it is not really clean