# Handling multiple git branches: stash or clone-per-branch?

Tags: git, git-stash

I would be interested in both general case and more specific answers, but some relevant factors in my particular case are:

- I'm currently the lone developer on this project, but might be collaborating with another in the near future
- I'm attempting to follow [this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), more-or-less.
- In particular regard to the previous point, two branches (master and develop) have remotes, other branches created for hotfixes, bugs, and features are local-only
- The repo is easy to clone and run/develop/test multiple instances of locally

On a day-to-day basis, I'm frequently working on several branches concurrently. Much of this work isn't immediately committable, so I'm currently using `git stash` to save work between branch switches. However, I'm finding working with stashes a bit fiddly and wondering if a clone-per-branch approach might be easier to keep track of. What are the advantages/disadvantages of each, and does anyone strongly recommending one approach over the other?

UPDATE: I should add that my reluctance to keep all branches constantly committed is because of an aversion to having broken or really bad code in the repo. I realise, however, that it might be wise to revise this principle, especially if I gain familiarity with the git tools to mitigate any negative side-effects.

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but I think this answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25588087/2541573

Comment: I recommend against both stashing and multiple clones as a solution to the problem you describe.  If something might ever be useful again, it is committable.  Use `git commit --amend` , interactive reabsing and `git reset` to keep your history clean, if you are so inclined, or just keep the history as it actually happened.

Comment: Great suggestion, sven. I might have a play around with --amend, which looks like a potential solution.

Comment: This answer by torek is also of interest, especially regarding the dangers of automating stash save and pop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27698341/2541573

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `git stash`. It's hard to sort back which stash belongs to which branch.

Instead, do a `git commit --all -m "stash"` and a `git reset HEAD~` when I continue working.

This leaves all stashes where they belong (i.e. on their branches).

Even better: leave all the stashes where they are. Once you finish your feature, use `git rebase -i` in order to clean up your history.

Comment: Actually, the default stash messages make it pretty straightforward to identify which branch a stash belongs to - at least, as far as I've gone yet. However, my problem is remembering to constantly apply the relevant stash after switching branch, and remembering to drop the relevant stash again afterwards.